# Angular project is Stuck with "Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)..."

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-builder

I tried to start my first project on angular and after giving the command,
CMD is stuck in:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

And not finishing at all. [Here it always stuck on this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMCUY.jpg)

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Were you able to figure out a solution?